# Handling null values in informatica flat files

Tags: informatica

Hi guys My code looks like

```
iif(not isnull(ltrim(rtrim(a))) or not is_spaces(ltrim(rtrim(a))) or ltrim(rtrim(a))!='' or length(ltrim(rtrim(a)))!=0 or ltrim(rtrim(a))!=null or ltrim(rtrim(a))!='NULL'and not isnull(ltrim(rtrim(b))) or not is_spaces(ltrim(rtrim(b))) or ltrim(rtrim(b))!='' or length(ltrim(rtrim(b)))!=0 or ltrim(rtrim(b))!=null or ltrim(rtrim(b))!='NULL',null,ltrim(rtrim(a))).
```

If both a and b are `not null` then i have to make a as `null` else pass the value of a as it is. But my logic is not working fine and I've checked with session logs by giving verbose data for expression transformation still my value of b which is `[NULL]` coming in session logs has been considered as `not null` . Can you please help me guys for giving exact statements to identify the null values properly.
 I've tried with is_spaces, empty `strings.length!=0` options. But still null values are considered as an actual values which is wrong.

Comment: Is it a fixed width file?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to group the conditions for `a` and `b` as shown below

```
IIF
(
     (
        NOT ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(a)))
     OR NOT IS_SPACES(LTRIM(RTRIM(a)))
     OR LTRIM(RTRIM(a)) != ''
     OR LENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(a))) != 0
     OR LTRIM(RTRIM(a)) != NULL
     OR LTRIM(RTRIM(a)) != 'NULL'
     )
    AND
     (
        NOT ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(b)))
     OR NOT IS_SPACES(LTRIM(RTRIM(b)))
     OR LTRIM(RTRIM(b)) != ''
     OR LENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(b))) != 0
     OR LTRIM(RTRIM(b)) != null
     OR LTRIM(RTRIM(b)) != 'NULL'
     )
  ,NULL
  ,LTRIM(RTRIM(a))
)
```

Hope this helps.

*NOTE*: I have not optimized your checks for checking `null` conditions.

Comment: Glad it worked! Could you mark this as an answer to indicate the same?